# Any open source alternative for ESRI maps for office

Tags: open-source-gis, software-recommendations, esri-maps-office

I am looking for an alternative for [ESRI maps for office](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/maps-for-office/). I know it is very good product for analyzing data within MS office environment.

My requirement:

-I have few stores data contains location details.

-Trying to analyzing the trend on the map itself in the excel document +Statistical analysis

-Is there any tool/app in the Open office(or MS Office & going through [EuroOffice tool](http://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/eurooffice-chart-map-professional) but it looks like its paid extension)?

-Researching on Google.

Comment: Do this have to be desktop driven? if not look at CartoDB http://cartodb.com/visualize

Comment: @Mapperz Going through your link

Answer (score 1):

The Caligra office suite has some mapping functionality, but not very mature I believe: See http://rockfordsone.blogspot.be/2011/08/marble-in-calligra.html

(Google has some stuff too, but not very open)

Comment: thanks for the reply..I will look into it and let you know..